# Viewing Google Earth Engine gallery datasets in standalone Google Earth client

Tags: google-earth

Google [Earth Engine](http://earthengine.google.org/) contains a number of interesting datasets in the *Featured gallery*:

> We have precomputed a number of interesting datasets using the Earth Engine platform, below. Click on each to learn more and preview the data as a global time-lapse or as a layer in a Google Earth client.

Then I click on any of them, I get *The Google Earth Plugin is currently only available on Windows and Mac OS X 10.6+.*.

How can I get those datasets directly in the stand-alone Google Earth client?  The standalone client has a button for *Earth gallery*, but that doesn't appear to contain those Earth Engine layers.

Even if I use the browser inside Google Earth to browse to the Earth Engine website, I get the message that the Google Earth plugin is not available on my platform.

Comment: Added an answer below. Separately, curious what platform you're using. Chrome on Linux?

Answer (score 1):

A hack would be to get links to the actual KMZ files by looking at the javascript source (http://earthengine.google.org/javascript/ee_js.js). Search that file for "kmz".

For example: http://mw1.google.com/ges/gallery/roadless.1km/root.kmz

Each url there can then be opened in Google Earth using the "Network Link" feature.